# Google Sheets: How to auto split a data set in half to create a control and test group based on a column variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am looking to split a data set in half (consisting of 1000's rows) automatically as the same action needs to be done daily. The difficulty is that I need each Slot start time segment to be halved and separated so that there is a control group and a test group.

I have attached a screenshot showing the data on the left (Slot start segments go from 05:30 all the way to 23:00 in 30 minute segments), then what my expected output is like on the right.

I suspect some VBA script will be required (no idea where to even start) - worth noting that the data will always be copied into the same cells, but the amount of data can vary as well as how many deliveries are in each time slot.

Screenshot of the data set on the left with the desired outcome on the right --

[image: 1]

Sample

| Customer No. | Delivery Date | Slot Start | Date Created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53930360 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63544585 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63541128 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63545763 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63541115 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63544705 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63537186 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63537827 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63501434 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63541573 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63518156 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63512742 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63542098 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63542387 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 44643633 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 50709070 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 60258231 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63475911 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63538324 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63528634 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63535031 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63534306 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63532381 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63547783 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63518590 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63539583 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 62220268 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |

Desired output

| Customer No. | Delivery Date | Slot Start | Date Created | Customer No. | Delivery Date | Slot Start | Date Created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53930360 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 | 63541115 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63544585 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 | 63544705 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63541128 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 | 63537186 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63545763 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 | 63537827 | 44855 | 05:30 | 44857 |
| 63501434 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63475911 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63541573 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63538324 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63518156 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63528634 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63512742 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63535031 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63542098 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63534306 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 63542387 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63532381 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 44643633 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63547783 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 50709070 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63518590 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
| 60258231 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 | 63539583 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |
|  |  |  |  | 62220268 | 44855 | 06:00 | 44857 |

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: I have now added the suggested text tables

Comment: Yes the times always go from 05:30 to 23:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is elegant and achieves what the OP needs. If someone wants to go the Apps Script way, here's one approach:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const rawSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Raw');
  const testSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test Group');
  const controlSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Control Group');

  const rawData = rawSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // Returns a 2D array
  const headerRow = rawData.shift();
  const timestampColumn = rawData.map(row => row[2])
  const uniqueTimestamps = timestampColumn.filter((time, index) => timestampColumn.indexOf(time) === index);
  let testGroupAll = [headerRow];
  let controlGroupAll = [headerRow];
  for (time of uniqueTimestamps) {
    // slotData is test group after splicing below
    const slotData = rawData.filter(row => row[2] === time);
    const controlGroup = slotData.splice(0, Math.round(slotData.length / 2));
    Logger.log(slotData); // test group - 2D array
    Logger.log(controlGroup); // 2D array
    testGroupAll = testGroupAll.concat(slotData);
    controlGroupAll = controlGroupAll.concat(controlGroup);
  }
  Logger.log(testGroupAll);
  Logger.log(controlGroupAll);
  testSheet.getDataRange().clear();
  controlSheet.getDataRange().clear();
  testSheet.getRange(1, 1, testGroupAll.length, 4).setValues(testGroupAll);
  controlSheet.getRange(1, 1, controlGroupAll.length, 4).setValues(controlGroupAll);
}
```

[Edit]: That was unexpected. Thank you for reconsidering and marking this as the accepted answer. I'd like to reiterate that the answer from @player0 is elegant, though not comprehensible, but that's due to the nature of formulae themselves - be it Google Sheets or good old MS Excel.

Those who are familiar with Google Sheets formulae would see that the use of `QUERY` with `limit` and `offset` alone takes away a lot of complexity that would otherwise have been there.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:D; "limit "&ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/2); 1)
```

and:

```
=QUERY(A:D; "offset "&ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/2); 1)
```

---

### UPDATE

same principle...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(MAP(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>""))*1, 
 LAMBDA(x, QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FILTER({A:C, D:D&"​"}, C:C=x), 
 "limit "&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTA(FILTER(A:A, C:C=x))/2), )),,9^9)),,9^9))),,9^9), "​")), " "))
```

and:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(MAP(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>""))*1, 
 LAMBDA(x, QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FILTER({A:C, D:D&"​"}, C:C=x), 
 "offset "&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTA(FILTER(A:A, C:C=x))/2), )),,9^9)),,9^9))),,9^9), "​")), " "))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response however that formula simply cuts the data in half through the middle, I need it to split each slot time. Here is a link with an example of the desired output. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tmrd1_LA2EHYQixiOeE6ys1MzFBYVSqG23dJOO8rtZg/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Gavin sheet is private

Comment: Are you able to request access to it as I am unable to make it open by default? The screenshot I have shared in the original post also visualises the desired output.

Comment: @Gavin I cant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmNBs.png

Comment: Thank you very much that works exactly as intended, much appreciated! Some high level wizardry indeed!!